# What is Brake To Vacate (BTV)?

Tags: landing, runways, airbus, airbus-a380, braking

Emirates has this feature on many of its A380s. From what I've read, the feature decreases the amount of runway an aircraft uses after landing. It also helps the aircraft achieve a certain exit way. Is this feature unique with only Aibus aircraft? How is it set up on an aircraft and how does BTV work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the Airbus website, Brake to Vacate is a feature installed on newer A-380s and also on the new A-350XWB that allows the pilot to select which runway exit s/he needs to use, and the system will brake hard enough, but just hard enough, to slow the plane to taxi speed by that turnoff.  This minimizes time on the runway.  The following quote is from the Airbus website.

> Brake to Vacate allows pilots to select the appropriate runway exit during the approach to landing, and regulates the aircraft’s deceleration after touchdown – enabling it to reach any chosen exit at the correct speed under optimum conditions, no matter the weather and visibility.

To my knowledge, Airbus is the only aircraft manufacturer to incorporate this feature - to date.

This feature does not reduce the amount of runway the aircraft uses.  Maximum Braking is still maximum braking.  It does however, optimize the braking so that the aircraft gets to the taxiway intersection sooner (doesn't brake too hard too soon, keeping speed up) and also prevents overshooting the intersection requiring a relatively slow taxi to the next turn off.

Comment: The predecessor to BTV is simply AutoBrakes, where a level of braking can be selected in the cockpit, each level corresponding to a deceleration level.  (On some Boeings, A/B 1 is very mild, A/B 2 is a fairly normal stop, A/B 3 is moderately firm, and A/B 4 is extremely firm braking, enough to get AntiSkid cycling & producing an uncomfortably rapid stop on a dry runway.) While pilots can override the autobrakes, you do that based on visual cues of how rapidly you need to slow to make "that' turnoff. BTV automates that process, aiming to avoid slowing too soon or braking too firmly at the end.

Comment: Does this mean on the A380 there is no autobrake function at all, and its completely replaced by BTV? Do you expect it to be introduced on smaller aircraft in the future? I am trying to understand is BTV something necessitated by the size of the A380 or its upgraded stopping requirements, or is this a general improvement in overall autobraking technology that may be seen in other aircraft in the future?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid BTV is an _enhancement_ to the existing autobrake system, so the regular Airbus autobrake settings would also be available. It's entirely a convenience for the pilots, so in theory any plane with an autobrake system could have something similar.

Comment: In addition to previously mentioned, BTV also reduces brake wear, because it optimizes the usage of wheelbrakes to as late as possible. This way aerodynamic braking and reverse thrust slows the aircraft first and wheelbrakes are used as little (and late) as possible.